# Django - replace form widget for fields in list

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to change the widget to fields in a form which have a string in the name, I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
class CI_tableForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = CI_table
            fields = report_query_values
            for field in report_query_values:
                if "_id" in field:
                    field = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

Not sure if it's possible or not.
At the moment it doesn't error, but doesn't change the widget either.

Thanks,
Isaac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it in the `__init__` constructor:

```
class CI_tableForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CI_table
        fields = report_query_values

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CI_tableForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in report_query_values:
            if "_id" in field:
                choices = self.fields[field].widget.choices
                self.fields[field].widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(
                                                             choices=choices)
```

Comment: I've tried something similar and used the __init__.py file in the main application folder, but didn't work.Should have I changed another init file?

Comment: I've tried again and I think the problem is in how I get the report_query_values, which I get from the url: report_query_values = QueryDict(request.META['QUERY_STRING']).keys()

Comment: I am talking about [`__init__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) method, not the `__init__.py` file.

Comment: Sorry, got confused there. I've added as you said and it's partially working. The widget is changed but it comes as empty, it doesn't load the options from the foreign key value as it did with the default

Comment: I updated the answer.  You have to get the `choices` attribute from the old widget and pass it to the `CheckboxSelectMultiple`.